# My api methods won't run after implementing a new method

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

```
public class ContactsController : ApiController
{
    static readonly IContactsRepository repository = new ContactsRepository();
    //
    // GET: /Contacts/

    public IEnumerable<Contact> GetAllContacts()
    {
        return repository.GetAll();
    }

}
```

The above code works fine with the API Call /api/contacts/GetAllContacts and returns a list of contacts from my database. I also want to add an method which returns a specific contact using something like /api/contacts/getcontacts? However, once I add in the following code:

```
public Contacts GetContact(int id)
{
    Contacts item = repository.Get(id);
    if (item == null)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
    return item;
}
```

My original call (/api/contacts/GetAllContact) will not work and displays the following error:

```
"Message": "The request is invalid.",
"MessageDetail": "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'ReservationsAPI.Models.Contacts GetContact(Int32)' in 'ReservationsAPI.Controllers.ContactsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."
```

EDIT:
route config

```
{
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
}
```

Comment: In the second block, public Contacts GetContact method, return type is Contacts, is it correct? Or it's just Contact?

Comment: This looks like a routing issue. Can you post your route config?

Comment: @SerkanHolat I am confused now because I have both and don't know which one I should return. I manually created a class called ContactS in my model folder. and when I press go to definition  for Contact, I get to a auto-generated class file. I am not sure about the difference between the two.

Comment: @NWard I am not familiar with routing config. Where can I get this info?

Comment: App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs

Comment: You need to change your routing so that you can specify the *action* on your controller instead of just an id.

Comment: As @NWard said, it should be `api/{controller}/{action}/{id}`

Comment: Yes, probably both of these things. Include the `{action}` in your routing, and you'll want to change your parameter to either `int?` or `string` (and just convert to int in your method).

Answer (score 1):

Remove ContactS class that you manually created and try this;

```
public class ContactController : ApiController
{
    static readonly IContactsRepository repository = new ContactsRepository();

    // GET api/Contact
    public IEnumerable<Contact> GetContact()
    {
        return repository.GetAll();
    }

    // GET api/Contact/5
    public IHttpActionResult GetContact(int id)
    {
        var contact = repository.Get(id);
        if (contact == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        return contact;
    }
```

Then try to call these urls;

```
/api/Contact
/api/Contact/1
```

With this setup, you don't need to define action in your routing.